# In shell,how to make a comand2 as a continue for comand1

Tags: shell

I have a shell file,I want to use it like

```
./flow.sh connect localhost login user password
```

after connect success,it will wait for the next command,
and then I will input the second command like

```
deploymenet xxxx.xml
```

now my question is how to make the 2 command into 1 command line because I want to call it in a ruby file.
The way I use to call shell in ruby is like "%x[command1;command2]".but it will got error because comand2 will be treated as a shell command,not a input after cammand1.

how to solve this? thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried feeding it to stdin of the process object?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams you mean like:./flow.sh connect localhost login user password<<<deploymenet xxxx.xml? The result is connect success,but got error"Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

Comment: Regd the error you get: Does it work, if you do it manually? Enter `./flow.sh .... ` command & in the prompt, enter `deployment ....` command manually.

Comment: @anishsane yes ,it works fine,no error for manually input

Comment: Worst case, try `expect` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo 'deploymenet xxxx.xml' | ./flow.sh connect localhost login user password
```

Comment: Got error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tool.ActivitRest.main(ActivitRest.java:117), but deploy xml is success in database

Comment: Without knowing what's in `flow.sh`, I can't help with that.

Comment: Actually,it's simple,just call some jar.I'll try to solve that myself. Thanks for giving help.